# When a God takes Avatar, what happens to the God in the original form?

Tags: vishnu, gods, avatars

When a God takes avatar, what happens to the original God form. Does He remain as it is or is depleted or altered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial and Full incarnations](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/partial-and-full-incarnations)

Comment: Supreme Lord is complete and absolute. even though so many emanations come from Him; all His emanations are complete and He too remains complete. You can read more here http://www.vedabase.com/en/iso/invocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He remains the same, only manifests in a physical form:

> "The avatar role-plays with deliberate and voluntary self-limitation.
>   The avatar has infinite knowledge which he can choose to access,
>   though ordinarily he does not, or else does so selectively"

In this also, there are two types of manifestation:

> “For the purpose of creation, the Divine Being assumes several
>   presiding personalities; each oversees the manifestation of particular
>   truths. A given personality may choose to manifest as a full
>   incarnation – in which case it is called an avatar – or as an
>   embodiment of its particular truth – in which case it is called a
>   vibhuti. Thus, avatar is God in visible form, and vibhuti is the
>   manifestation of one or more of his infinite qualities. In other
>   words, an avatar is a vibhuti, but a vibhuti is not necessarily an
>   avatar. For example, Krishna is an avatar as well as a vibhuti, but
>   Arjuna is a vibhuti only. Ushana, the brave king, likewise is a
>   vibhuti”

-Excerpt from the book 'Being Different' by Rajiv Malhotra.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Vishnu, His very name means One Who is present everywhere; so the Lord does not need to disappear somewhere else in order to be manifest before our senses. He is already here, He simply chooses where and where to manifest Himself.